# Flex, rotations (x,y,z) when component resized

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I've started learning flex and as a first project I've created a component from the example found [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/02/rotating-an-image-along-its-x-axis-y-axis-and-z-axis-in-flex-and-flash-player-10/) component with  which I call into the main application (web based).

When I rotate the image it goes well,
however, when I resize the application, my component which fills the application container ie width, height 100%, seems to make the rotations calculus based on it's previous width and height.

So basically the rotations go wrong when I resize the app. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to recalculate the view's perspective point upon the app resize event.